# itextsharp copy a pdf with empty fields add it to pdf , read fields only of first page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

When I press a button, the items of the checkedlistbox should be written in a PDF. The PDF document has 1 page with 20 fields but it should be flexible. So if the checkedlistbox has 52 entries for example, the program creates a PDF with 3 pages (copy the pdf and add it 2 times). This works, but the fields of the following pages have the same name as the first. I hope this isn't a problem.

Then it reads the field names:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(path);
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfReader.AcroFields;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> kvp in pdfFormFields.Fields) {
    listoffieldnames.Add(kvp.Key.ToString());
}
pdfReader.Close();
```

My problem is, the reader only reads the fields of the first page.

Answer (score 0):

> the program creates a PDF with 3 pages (copy the pdf and add it 2 times). This works, but the fields of the following pages have the same name as the first. I hope this isn't a problem.

Well, this *is* a problem.

A PDF has only a single abstract form definition in which a field uniquely is identified by its fully qualified name. A field, on the other hand, can have multiple widgets, i.e. multiple visualizations, which may differ in display details (e.g. might use different fonts or font sizes) but which all show the same value.

Code copying multiple copies of the same source PDF into a target PDF may handle this in different ways:

- It might ignore the field uniqueness issue and create a PDF with multiple form fields with the same name.
- It might recognize duplicate field names and merge those fields with the same name as multiple widgets of a single field.
- It might recognize duplicate field names and rename duplicates to eventually have unique names.

(If you used iTextSharp to create these copies: iTextSharp can be used in different ways to merge PDFs, either fast and dumb or not quite so fast and intelligent, implementing either the second or third option.)

How PDFs created in the dumb first way are handled by PDF viewers differs for different viewers and even different versions of the same viewer: The duplicate fields either are interpreted as multiple widgets of the same field or only one of the fields with the same name is handled as a proper field and the others are inactive / defunct.

As in your case *the fields of the following pages have the same name as the first*, your copying code is one of the first two types, so if multiple copies of the same field are functional at all, they represent the same single form field.